# How do I add text and other things in tabs 2 and three?

Tags: android, android-studio, tabbed-interface

I'm using Android Studios tabbed activity template with ActionBar Tabs, I have a slight problem. I want to be able to add different texts into the different tabs however I get the same text on all tabs. How would I go by doing this?

[image: Tabbed Activities]

I have read through all the comments on the code yet still can't find how the different tabs are linked.

public class ScriptsTabbed extends ActionBarActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

```
/**
 * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
 * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
 * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
 * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
 * may be best to switch to a
 * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
 */
SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

/**
 * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
 */
ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_scripts_tabbed);




    // Set up the action bar.
    final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the activity.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    // When swiping between different sections, select the corresponding
    // tab. We can also use ActionBar.Tab#select() to do this if we have
    // a reference to the Tab.
    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }
    });

    // For each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.
    for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        // Create a tab with text corresponding to the page title defined by
        // the adapter. Also specify this Activity object, which implements
        // the TabListener interface, as the callback (listener) for when
        // this tab is selected.
        actionBar.addTab(
                actionBar.newTab()
                        .setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                        .setTabListener(this));
    }
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_scripts_tabbed, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab1, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    // When the given tab is selected, switch to the corresponding page in
    // the ViewPager.
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab1.getPosition());



}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab2, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab2.getPosition());


        }

@Override
public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab3, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab3.getPosition());

}

/**
 * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
 * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
 */
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
        return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
            case 1:
                return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
            case 2:
                return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);
        }
        return null;
    }
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    /**
     * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
     * number.
     */
    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }


    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_scripts_tabbed, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

}

Thank you!

Comment: Share you adapter code for viewpager

Comment: @Fahim is that what you wanted?

Comment: SectionsPagerAdapter code needed

Comment: Not sure which part, so I added the whole code. @Fahim

Comment: You want different layout for different tab content?

Comment: Nope I want to add a unique type of text into each tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer this how I update the content based of selected tab

```
  // In this case, the fragment displays simple text based on the page 
    public class PageFragment extends Fragment { 
    public static final String ARG_PAGE = "ARG_PAGE";
     private int mPage;
     public static PageFragment newInstance(int page) {
     Bundle args = new Bundle();
     args.putInt(ARG_PAGE, page);
     PageFragment fragment = new PageFragment();
     fragment.setArguments(args);

     return fragment; 
    }
     @Override 
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    mPage = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PAGE);
 }
     // Inflate the fragment layout we defined above for this fragment 
    // Set the associated text for the title 
    @Override
     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_page, container, false); 
    TextView tvTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
     tvTitle.setText("Fragment #" + mPage);
     return view;
     }     }
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, however one problem.
 public static PageFragment newInstance(int page) {

IDE says "Inner classes can not have static declarations" and 

PageFragment fragment = new PageFragment();

"Mypackagename can not be referenced from a static context"

Comment: Make page fragment class as static

Comment: Yes that is done however I still get " New Text" on all the tabs, instead of one.

Comment: You mean tab name is not changing as u mentioned in the screen shot?

Comment: Nope the tab name is fine, I want to change the contents of the tab. So in Tab One i want the text AAA
Tab Two i want the text BBB
Tab Three I want the text CCC. 

At the moment Tab one, two and three all display AAA. @Fahim